# JSON parsing error in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am working on an in-house web app that uses Pylons on the backend, and I find myself in need of help figuring out why I'm getting JSON parsing errors.

The Python routine on the server is effectively this:

```
import json

# Other Pylons imports here

# Snip...

def validateMachine(self):
  retObj = {}
  retObj['ipv4addr'] = '10.10.15.9'
  retObj['netmask'] = '255.255.255.0'
  return json.dumps(retObj)
```

The client side has the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/kickstart/validateMachine",
  data: {theData: theValue},
  dataType: "json"
 })
 .done(function(data) {
  retObj = $.parseJSON(data);
  #Other code here
 });
```

When I execute the AJAX query, the server routine returns correctly, but the call to $.parseJSON() errors out. A screenshot of the Firebug console after it's errored out:
[image: JSON error console]

The response appears to be valid strict JSON, so my question is two-fold: why is it not parsing correctly, and how can I get it to do so? It's my understanding that jQuery is (correctly) attempting to use the browser's native JSON parser in this case - can I somehow override that and tell jQuery to not use the native parser?

Comment: IMHO, when setting the expected dataType to JSON, you don't need to parse manually, data is JSON already. Have you checked `typeof data`?

Comment: When you specify `json`, jQuery automatically parses the response for you. Therefore, `data` is already a native js object, and calling `parseJSON` on the js object causes an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot parseJSON on an object that is already a json object, seeing that the data is already a JSON according to your images

```
{"netmask": "255.255.255.0", "ipv4addr": "10.10.15.9"}
```

So this should be enough

```
retObj = data;
```